Trying to integrate my database in my ASP.NET project
I have a problem, I'm doing a college work and my teacher asked to integrate the database directly on my project. The idea behind this is to export the project and be able to execute the page without modifications in other PC/laptop.
My page directory looks like this right now:
WebApplication1
|  Connected Services
|  Dependencies
|  Properties
|  wwwroot
|  Data
|  |   dataBaseHelper.cs
|  |   MyDb.mdf
|  Pages
|  appsettings.json
|  Program.cs

I tried to put this line to connect it on my appsetting.Development.json:
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Data\\MyDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

but it doesn't work, it shows this error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(string connectionString)

and my connection string use that DefaultConnection:
public DatabaseHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
{ 
    _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
}

I tried using other ways to connect it based on some research I made, using this connection for example
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

and it shows this other error

SqlException: Cannot open database "MyDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-H14KUIC\nicol'


Do you have SQL server installed and up and running? Do you have the sql browser service up and running? You thus require SQL server to be installed and running before you attempt the attach

yeah, i have the server running, still it just doesn't work for some reason, if i just try it, using a static direction, for example "C:\Users\nicol\Documents\MyDb.mdf" it works just fine, but using the one that is on my proyect, it dont want to work
